# reg.ru - how do I update Xwiki via Jelastic?

Tags: jelastic, xwiki

This is directed at Reg.ru support team: I'd liek to update the version of XWiki from 6.0 to the latest version but I don't know how to. I think you guys might have to update your repository. Could you please let me know if this is possible?

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the official Xwiki site is provided good instructions. You can find it by the following link - http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/Upgrade

I have easy upgraded my Xwiki version from the 6.0.1 to the 6.4.2 (http://xwiki-1320854.jelastic.regruhosting.ru/).

Comment: oh d&mn, that was easy. Thanks!